# Use aliases with exec in a non-interactive shell

Tags: node.js, bash, ssh, exec, yarnpkg

During a deployment process I run `yarn install` over an SSH connection in a non-interactive shell. Since an alternative node.js version (default version 8.x on the server is too low) must be used, an alias is created and loaded in the bash script over the SSH connection:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.bashrc

node -v
```

The .bashrc script looks like:

```
export PATH=/opt/plesk/node/12/bin/node:$PATH
alias node="/opt/plesk/node/12/bin/node"
```

Running `node -v` will print the correct version 12.x. The correct version is also output when executing JavaScript code:

```
node -e "console.log(process.versions.node);"
```

But yarn calls node internally with exec (https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/master/bin/yarn#L20). And this will call the default version of node instead of the alias version. That means `yarn versions` lists node 8.x.

This is only the case with a non-interactive bash. If I call this in an interactive shell, yarn internally uses the correct node version 12.x of the alias.

How can I run yarn in a non-interactive bash with the correct node version?

Comment: Just add `/opt/plesk/node/12/bin` to the `PATH`. The alias is unnecessary.

Comment: @chepner I have updated the `.bashrc` script above. I already set the `PATH` variable. But that doesn't work either.

Comment: Just the directory *containing* `node` goes in the `PATH` variable, not the full path to the executable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was my mistake. It has to be `export PATH=/opt/plesk/node/12/bin:$PATH`, of course.